# not getting click even there is match

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

code

```
from http.server import executable
from multiprocessing.connection import wait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe") 


driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element(By.NAME,"q").send_keys('myi')
print(driver.title)

optionsList = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//body/div[@class='L3eUgb']//form[@role='search']//div[@class='A8SBwf emcav']//div[@class='mkHrUc']/ul[1]/div[@role='presentation']/ul[@role='listbox']")
print(len(optionsList))

for searchtxt in optionsList:
    print(searchtxt.text)
    
    if searchtxt.text == 'myip':
        searchtxt.click()
        break

time.sleep(25)

driver.quit()
```

terminal

```
PS C:\Users\mrmad\Desktop\selenium test> & C:/Users/mrmad/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe "c:/Users/mrmad/Desktop/selenium test/google.py"
c:\Users\mrmad\Desktop\selenium test\google.py:11: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe")

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55485/devtools/browser/87772c6f-7fa4-4186-81e6-7f1964cb27d4
Google
1
myip
myims
myitreturn
myims login
myinterview practice.com
myiasis
myimaginestore
myinfo lakehead
myillini
myimmitracker
[6992:11244:0730/224205.248:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [22:42:05.247] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[6992:11244:0730/224205.249:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [22:42:05.249] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

im getting print list of search of myi you can see there is myip in terminal printed list so it should be match with my if condition and it will be click so i should get myip searched on google somehow im not getting it
and also there is i have print lenth of list here it is 1 but i think it shouldn't be you can see im getting 10 search result so it should be 10

using

```
chrome - 103.0.5060.134
chromewebdriver - 103.0.5060.134
python- 3.10.5
selenium - 4.3.0
```

Comment: Try to print whole optionsList to actually see what does it represent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your `XPATH` is wrong, what you are doing currently is get all the `ul` tags in your page. However what you really need to do here is to get all `li` elements since all your autocomplete suggestions are stored in `li`.

Although your XPATH string can be optimized, but I would keep it the way you have with a simple change.

```
optionsList = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//body/div[@class='L3eUgb']//form[@role='search']//div[@class='A8SBwf emcav']//div[@class='mkHrUc']/ul[1]/div[@role='presentation']/ul[@role='listbox']/li")
```

Now this should work.

Comment: thanks man my xpath is wrong i have specific selected first search result thats my mistake without your solution i would not have come too see this small mistake

Comment: i have one more question okay my xpath is wrong but how am getting all search result list printed in terminal and also print statement is in for loop so im getting print myip it should match to my if condition right .. sorry being noobie here just started learning py selenium so deep explanation or boring answer also welcome please

Comment: You are getting everything printed on terminal because you got the parent element and hence you would see the length of list is 1 and when you do get text it gives you text from the parent element which obviously contains all li tags inside it

Answer (score 0):

You .. probably don't need long xpaths to get those elements. Here is a (slightly) more robust solution, which will dismiss the cookie button if it comes up, wait for the elements to load, search for your string, go through the results and click on the relevant one:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")


webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
url = 'https://www.google.com'
browser.get(url)
try:
    deny_cookies = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='W0wltc']")))
    deny_cookies.click()
except Exception as e:
    print('no cookies')
search_box = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='q']")))
search_box.send_keys('myi')
search_box.click()
options = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@data-view-type='1']")))
for option in options:
    print(option.text)
    if option.text == 'myip':
        option.click()
        break
```

The selenium/chrome setup is for linux, however the relevant parts are:

- imports: WebDriverWait, expected_conditions, By
- the part after browser.get(url), where we explicitly wait for the elements to load and be clickable

Comment: not getting anything on your xpath 
(By.XPATH, "//li[@data-view-type='1']")
may be its linux thing idk 
you sure getting result like searching myi and auto select myip

Comment: It could be due to the fact Google page has a different structure in my country. However, you should have been able to learn from my example, and adapt it  (including element selectors) to the page loaded for you. Of course it works for me.